# React - import a module in node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs

What's the correct way to import a module from node_modules into a react app?

When I do: `import MyModule from '../node_modules/my_module'`

I get: `Module not found: You attempted to import ../node_modules/my_module which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/`

Don't tell me I'm supposed to copy node_modules into src/ everytime?

Note: I'm on windows which has no symlinks.

Comment: What's the problem with `import MyModule from 'my_module'` ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to import some modules from node_modules, you just need to say, for example, import the whole exported module:

```
import React from "react";
```

or import part of the exported module:

```
import { Router } from "react-router"
```

"react", and "react-router" are modules in your node_modules folder.

Comment: I had tried that, apparently I needed to restart the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

import syntax should use {export name} from './';

but if you use export default, you are possible to just use export name.

and also, The module installed from npm doesn't need path. Just use module name

e.g) `import {React, Component} from 'react';`