# How to stop import of node modules with relative paths in React, VS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I have been using VS code for my React development for over a month now and everything was okay, until recently i noticed something odd, about how node modules were imported in project.

Initially, they were imported as follows, which i believe is the right way:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

But now, they are imported like:

```
import { useNavigate } from "../../../node_modules/react-router-dom/index";
```

Please help, how can I revert this behaviour.

Comment: Check this link out [is full path required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588298/is-full-path-required-in-imports-in-node-modules-in-javascript-react)

Comment: Thank you for that insight, but it discusses a different issue from mine. So i couldn't get help from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem from the VS code GitHub issues section.

This was an issue caused by an extension i installed - `"Babel Javascript"`.

According to this [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53597#issuecomment-404099158), I had to switch the language in the bottom bar of VS code being detected from `Babel Javascript` to `Javascript`. that solved the issue.

To prevent the issue from recurring, i also disabled the `Babel Javascript` plugin.